# How to add customized button in multi select?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using Bootstrap's multi-select and I'm trying to add button.
i want to add button as shown below
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoMo1.png)

```
<select  multiple="multiple" class="form-control ">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option><button>ADD new</button></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You will need to add that button into the generated HTML, not into the orignal SELECT. Choose an appropriate event from that plugin to modify the HTML after initialization.

Comment: i want button to be inside option

Comment: @ feeela  can u explain me in brief like which even to use

Comment: go to the site where you get the image, press F12, inspect the html code to see how they did that, then you can go and try something similar. But for now, the button isn't inside the `select`, it's probably other html element appended to the bottom of the select

Comment: @user6688672 try to use https://select2.org/ plugin which have many options and methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple HTML code:

```
<select  multiple="multiple" class="form-control ">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option><input type="button" value="Add New"/></option>
</select>
```

This will create a new button inside option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put buttons into a select element. jQuery's Bootstrap Select plugin puts two buttons (select/deselect all) inside the menu because it basically replaces it with an unordered list styled like a select dropdown. You can have a look at it (https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and how it manages the "actionsBox" option and hook your code on that same events.

Alternatively you can go your own way with styling an unordered list by yourself.